# Understand a FM question about a bond with varying interest rate.

Tags: solution-verification, problem-solving, finance, compound-interest

Consider a coupon bond with maturity in $2$ years, with a coupon rate of $4.375\%$ (coupons are paid twice a year) and with a face value of $100€$. Let's say this coupon bond has a varying continuously compounded interest rate, in the sense that for each half year we have a different continuously compounded interest rate. Furthermore, assume you also know the following discount factors:

$$ B(t,0.5) = 0.978 \quad B(t,1) = 0.957 \quad B(t,1.5) = 0.937 \quad \text{ and } \quad B(t,2) = 0.917. $$

Compute the price of this bond.

**My interpretation of the problem.** According to the coupon rate and to the face value, I was able to determine the value of each coupon, which came out to be $c = 2.1875€$. On the other hand, I believe that I understood the idea behind the exercise. Essentialy, the bond in question has different interest rates $r_1,r_2,r_3$ and $r_4$ in the following way: in the first half year, interest rate $r_1$ is applied, in the second half of the first year the interest rate $r_2$ is applied and so on. What I really can't understand is how to use the discount factors provided in order the determine the price of the bond. I think that, mainly, I am having a hard time understanding exactly what is a discount factor because in my mind the values provided don't make much sense.

So, in essence, I am looking for hints that can lead me to solve this exercise and I think my main problem is in understanding what a discount factor is, for this particular  bond.

Thanks for any help in advance.

Comment: What do the $B$ function and "discount factors" mean? Do they just mean that, for example, $c\cdot B(t,0.5)$ is the present value of the first coupon?

Comment: @peterwhy That's exactly my question, I can't understand what a discount factor may be in this context and even more, I can't even think of a meaning that makes sense for this context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The notation $B(t,T)$ means the price at time $t < T$ of a zero-coupon bond that is redeemable for the face value (principal) of 1€ at maturity time $T$. The buyer of this pure-discount bond is receiving a continuously compounded interest rate of $r_T$ given by

$$B(t,T) =e^{-r_T(T-t)},$$

when the bond is held to maturity and the principal payment is received.

The coupon bond that makes coupon payments of 2.19€ every $6$ months and repays the principal of 100€ along with the final coupon payment in two years is equivalent to a package of zero-coupon bonds.  Given the current market price of those zero-coupon bonds, the fair value of the coupon bond (precluding any arbitrage opportunities) must be

$$P(t) = 2.19B(t,0.5) + 2.19B(t,1) + 2.19B(t,1.5) + 102.19B(t,2)= 99.99€$$

Using the prices of the zero-coupon bonds in this way, you are finding the present value of the coupon bond with the different interest rates that are appropriate for each future payment date.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I believe that I understood your reasoning, but either way I'd like you to give me feedback on my understanding. The price of the original bond is given by $$ P(t) = 2.19e^{-0.5 \cdot r_1} + 2.19e^{-r_2} + 2.19e^{-1.5\cdot r_3} + 102.19e^{-2r_4}.$$ Wording this out, we are basically saying that the price of the original bond is no more than the sum of $4$ zero-coupon bonds (in this case, with different interest rates) and the values for each of these bonds is exactly the "discount factors" the exercise is giving me, correct?

Comment: @xyz: Yes - you are correct.  If a trader sees a discrepancy between the price of a Treasury bond and the equivalent package of (zero-coupon) Treasury strips even allowing for bid-ask spread, they can make a quick profit by a suitable long-short trade.  Such opportunities seldom arise and are fleeting.

Comment: After re-thinking about this problem and re-reading your answer, I figured that I don't quite agree with it. Follows my reasoning: In fact, we know that $$ B(t,0.5) = 0.978 $$ and the interest rate in the period $[0,0.5]$ is fixed and equal to $r_1$. Thus, in this particular case I agree with you. Now let us consider $B(t,1).$ We have that $B(t,1) = 0.957$ but I don't agree that $B(t,1) = e^{-r_2}.$ In my opinion, we should have $B(t,1) = e^{-0.5r_1-0.5r_2}.$ Am I missing something or is my reasoning correct?

Comment: @xyz: The convention for zero-coupon bonds is as I stated above The price corresponding to a maturity date $T$ is $B(t,T) = e^{-r_T(T-t)}$ where $r_T$ is the interest rate for the period from present until the maturity date.   To keep things simple let $t=0$.    Then $B(0,0.5) = e^{-r_{0.5}(0.5)} = 0.978$.  The continuous rate for that 6-month period is then $-\ln(0.978)= 2.2246\%$ and on an annualized basis that is $2.2246\%/0.5 = 4.4491\%$.  The next zero-coupon bond price $B(0,1)$ determines the continuous rate of compounding over the full 1-year period which is $-\ln(0.957) = 4.3952\%$.

Comment: For $B(0,2) = 0.917$, the rate for the two-year period is $-\ln(0.917) = 8.6648/%$.  To annualize that rate you divide by $2$ to get $r_2 = 4.3324\%$.  Note that in this way we see all the period rates are about $4.4\%$ indicating a flat yield curve.  If you want the effective rate from 6 months to 1 year -- that is called the forward rate and is computed in a different way.  Also it is a rate that applies to a forward rate agreement -- not any pure discount bond.

Comment: I think you didn't understand my question: let's say I have a zero coupon bond with maturity in $1$ year, facial value of $1$€ and such that on the first half the year we have a constinuously compounded interest rate of $4\%$ and on the second half of the year we have a $8\%$ continuously compounded interest rate. How would one calculate the price of this bond, i.e., $B(0,1)$?

Comment: What do you mean by "on the second half of the year we have a 8% continuously compounded interest rate"? What is typically called a zero-coupon bond that matures in one year has the same rate of interest specified in advance throughout the entire year.  There are floating rate instruments but they don't work like what you are describing. The rate at which interest accrues varies over time subject to periodic resets, but we don't know in advance what rate will apply in the future.  Furthermore, what does this have to do with the question.

Comment: Perhaps you are overthinking this. For an exercise like this where they give you the "discount factors" it is almost certain that the interpretation above is what is implied.